# How to save and retrieve two arrays in Core Data in iOS6

Tags: ios, core-data, nsarray

I have two arrays

1. `retrievedNamesMutableArray`
2. `retrievedImagesArray`

which I am saving in Core Data. Although the saving operation is successful, when I fetch data, it seems to fetch either Names or Images but not both. I assume I can store a NSDictionary in Core Data but can't seem to figure out a way to do it.

This is what I am doing to save to Core Data.

```
  -(void)saveToPhoneDatabase
{
   AddressBookAppDelegate *appDelegate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
   NSManagedObject *newContact;

  /* I assume this can be done but can't figure out proper process.
   NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
  [dictionary setObject:self.retrievedNamesMutableArray forKey:@"NamesArray"];
  [dictionary setObject:self.retrievedImagesArray forKey:@"ImagesArray"];
  */

   for (NSString *object in self.retrievedNamesMutableArray)
   {
    newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AddressBook" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newContact setValue:@"GroupOne" forKey:@"groups"];
    [newContact setValue:object forKey:@"firstName"];

   }

   for (UIImage *img in self.retrievedImagesArray)
   {
     newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AddressBook" inManagedObjectContext:context];
     [newContact setValue:img forKey:@"photo"];
     NSLog(@"Saved the photos of Array");
   }

  [context save:nil];
}
```

This is how I fetch.

```
-(void)fetchFromPhoneDatabase
{
   AddressBookAppDelegate *appDelegate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
   NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AddressBook" inManagedObjectContext:context];
   NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
   [request setEntity:entityDesc];
   NSError *error;
   self.arrayForTable = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

   NSLog(@"contents from core data = %@",self.arrayForTable);

  [self.tableView reloadData];

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first loop creates objects containing a name but no image, and your second loop create *different* objects containing an image but no name.

Assuming (from your previous questions) that both arrays have the same size, you should
create only one object for each name/image:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [self.reterivedNamesMutableArray count]; i++) {
    NSString *object = self.reterivedNamesMutableArray[i];
    UIImage *img = self.reterivedImagesArray[i];

    newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AddressBook" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newContact setValue:@"GroupOne" forKey:@"groups"];
    [newContact setValue:object forKey:@"firstName"];
    [newContact setValue:img forKey:@"photo"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That took care of everything...just one question though...how can i set the image in table View Cell? I did this....AddressBook *info = [self.arrayForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           cell.textLabel.text = info.firstName; cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:info.photo]; which throws error.

Comment: @Sushrut: How is the "photo" attribute defined in the Core Data model? Which type does it have?

Comment: It is transformable , If i make it a Binary Data type , it throws a SIGABRT error.

Comment: @Sushrut: Does it work if you keep it transformable, but assign `cell.imageView.image = info.photo` ?

Comment: No.It throws an exception as well that says ..unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d67be0

Comment: Solved the problem....Actually i was storing UIImage for Binary data attribute .So i changed that to NSData.